# Schedule Task to run every 1 hour

Tags: c#

Hi I would like to schedule a Task which will be executed every 1 hour.

But the time consumed by the Task is somewhat "random" which means that it may take 30 minutes or it may also take 1h15min. Only one Task at a time must run.

I would like to be able to execute the Task and if the interval time elapsed it will run the Task directly, if the time not elapsed it will wait till the 1 hour complete.

What is the best way to do this?

I started to look at FluentScheduler but it does not allow me to configure a schedule with the scenario i described.

Comment: Can't you use the windows scheduler for this? Or else you can look at Quarz.NET.

Comment: If the first task takes  *1h15min*, when should the next task start?

Comment: BTW: *"What is the best way to do this?"*  type of questions make me always smile. You don't even have a working *way*, and you ask for the *best*.

Comment: Please take a look at the [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the useful comment, I will explore Quartz.NET it seems to be a powerful scheduler.

I managed to do a small (one job) "scheduler" to run in interval of one hour between each task.

I am using TPL.Dataflow, here's my code

```
TransformBlock<int, int> block = new TransformBlock<int, int>(i =>
{
    //Thread.Sleep(5000);
    DoSomething();
return i + 1;
});

block.LinkTo(block);
block.Post(0);
```

I know that is very fragile but it will do the job.
Thanks for the comments! I'll explore more possibilities.